# When Registering the user using firebase, it's data when fetched not rendered on screen directly instead displayed when refreshed?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit and firebase with react, when I am registering my user, it's data like name and image has to be rendered generally on the Navbar, but they are not rendered directly on screen instead rendered when refreshed.

```
//This is my Auth reducer
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const initialState = {
  currData: null,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCurrData: (state, action) => {
      state.currData = action.payload;
      
    },
  },
});

export const { setCurrData } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

```
// This is Code for my Navbar.
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { RootState } from "../interfaces/interfaces";

const Navbar = () => {
  const currData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth.currData);
  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", currData.uid);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      status: "off",
    });
    signOut(auth);
  };

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <span className="logo">Live Chat</span>
      <div className="user">
        {currData && (
          <>
            <img src={currData.photoURL as string} alt="User Image" />
            <span>{currData.displayName}</span>
          </>
        )}
        <button onClick={handleSignOut}>logout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

What I want is my Navbar gets updated Automatically with the data.
PS- Asking First Question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Where exactly do you dispatch your `setCurrData` action?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the correct and relevant code where you set any user details client-side. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the *relevant* code you are working with that has an issue.